# Change orientation on Phonegap JQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

Hi i write simple app using jqm and phonegap, and i have some problem with change orientation. I need to change orientation on one page. I can change values "Supported interface orientations" but it work on all pages, may be exist way to change orientation on one page ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this plugin.

https://github.com/champierre/pg-plugin-screen-orientation

To lock the screen to Landscape:

```
navigator.screenOrientation.set('landscape');
```

To lock the screen to Portrait:

```
navigator.screenOrientation.set('portrait');
```

To unlock:

```
navigator.screenOrientation.set('fullSensor');
```

Comment: Available for Android only.

Comment: This one works on Android, iOS and WP: 
https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated plugin which works perfectly for me: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation

To use it (for cordova version > 4) execute this command:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-screen-orientation
```

Or for phonegap:

```
phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-screen-orientation
```

Then use it like this:

```
screen.lockOrientation('portrait')
screen.lockOrientation('landscape')
```

Works for Android & iOS.